# Help with Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to delete all the records where field name `class="10010"` from Table A and `AentryId = BentryId` from Table B.

if i delete the entryId 12 which matches className=10010 from Table A and the same time that same id should delete from Table B also.

Table A:

```
AentryId  className     
12      10010
13      10011
14      10010
15      10011
```

Table B:

```
BentryId  name   
12         xyz
13         abc
14         aaa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is through a foreign key defined with CASCADE DELETE:

```
alter table B 
  add constraint b_a_fk foreign key (BentryId)
  references A (AentryId)
  on delete cascade
/
```

If you delete a row from A all its dependent records in B are automatically deleted.

Of course, enforcing a foreign key means that you cannot create any rows in B with a BentryId which does not reference a pre-existing AentryId in A.  This is normally a desirable thing but not every data model enforces relational integrity.

**edit**

Dropping the constraint really couldn't be simpler...

```
alter table B 
  drop constraint b_a_fk 
/
```

Comment: i have altered my table as you said. But now i want to remove the constraint for some reason...how to do that?

your swift action shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Following may be final query you are looking for

```
delete form TableA where   class="10010" and AentryId in ( select BentryId from tableB)
```

Cascade delete is one of the option that allow you to delete data from child and form primary table

otherwise you can write query like below

```
   declare @T table (id int)
   insert into @T  
      select AentryId form TableA where   class="10010" and AentryId in ( select BentryId from tableB)

  delete form TableA where  AentryId in ( select id from @T)
  delete form TableB where  BentryId in ( select id from @T)
```

Comment: This does meet the requirement: it needs to delete from table B as well.

Comment: Thanks for your query. But it is deleting the rows from TableA only not from TableB...